# Windows 2008R2 reporting low disk space - 500mb

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

I have a  server reporting very critically low diskspace. I have three 1TB drives with  installed and I would appreciate some advice on remedying this issue. I am considering using a   Spanned Disk as a single logical drive is this advisable client server environment.

Whats the best pratice for such a scenario.

Comment: Hire an admin. This is not the place to teach basics....

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them

Answer (score 1):

> I am considering using a Spanned Disk as a
>   single logical drive is this advisable client server environment.

No. It's bit not advisable in a production setting. In a spanned drive setting, if a single drive failed, your system would become unusable.

> Whats the best pratice for such a scenario.

There isn't You have not given enough info to give you any directed/specific advice. How are your drives configured now? Which drive is running out of space? Are you unable to free up space any other way? What kind of server?

A basic general best practice: use a quality RAID controller to create a redundant array out your multiple disks. This will likely require you to rebuild your server.